# "People and Groups" link missing from SPO Site Settings on Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, team-sites, site-settings

Last week I created a new Teams site. I am one of 3 owners, and I confirmed I'm still an owner. I have no other SharePoint authority at the farm level. I'm just a Teams site owner.

Last week I created a new "Editors" group and changed the permissions for the Document Library so Editors have Contribute and changed Members to Read access.

[image: Document Library Permissions]

Today when I go back into Site Settings, I no longer see the "People and Groups" option on my Site Settings. I can go to the **user.apsx** page by changing the URL (and I was able to make changes), but I'm sure I didn't do that last week.

Why is the "People and Groups" link gone? Is there any other way to navigate to the page besides changing the URL manually?

Here are my settings:

[image: Site Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another path to get to the page, but you have to start from the right place and go the right way. Once you get into the SharePoint Site Setting page, you can't get there.

- Open the Team and select the **Files** tab
- In the header, click the three dots and then **Open in SharePoint**
- In the upper right corner, click the gear icon, then click Site Permissions

  [image: Settings menu]
- In the **Permissions** sidebar at the bottom, click **Advanced permissions settings**
  [image: Permissions sidebar]

This will open the **user.aspx** page.